# How can I use front camera and back camera simultaneously on the iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How can I display the stream from the front camera and back camera at the simultaneously on the iPhone? Is this even possible?

Comment: Any updates since 2013?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is impossible.

Multiple cameras are not allowed simultaneously. So as soon as one session begins, the other will stop.